# How to make dependabot to keep same version for multiple Java libraries?

Tags: java, kotlin, github, gradle, dependabot

In my `build.gradle.kts` I have multiple libraries that are released simultaneously with the same version and must be kept that way. How do I make Github's Dependabot to update version of all of them at once, if it has detected that version change on one of the libraries?

Example:

```kotlin
  // these all must have the same version
  kapt("io.javalin.community.openapi:openapi-annotation-processor:5.3.2")
  api("io.javalin.community.openapi:javalin-openapi-plugin:5.3.2")
  api("io.javalin.community.openapi:javalin-swagger-plugin:5.3.2")
  api("io.javalin.community.openapi:javalin-redoc-plugin:5.3.2")
```

So far I have no idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by introducing file `libs.versions.toml` with content like this:

```ini
[versions]
javalin = "5.4.2"
kotlin = "1.8.20"

[libraries]
javalin = { module = "io.javalin:javalin", version.ref = "javalin" }
javalin-rendering = { module = "io.javalin:javalin-rendering", version.ref = "javalin" }
javalin-openapi = { module = "io.javalin.community.openapi:javalin-openapi-plugin", version.ref = "javalin" }
javalin-openapi-swagger = { module = "io.javalin.community.openapi:javalin-swagger-plugin", version.ref = "javalin" }
javalin-openapi-redoc = { module = "io.javalin.community.openapi:javalin-redoc-plugin", version.ref = "javalin" }
javalin-openapi-annotations-processor = { module = "io.javalin.community.openapi:openapi-annotation-processor", version.ref = "javalin" }

[plugins]
kotlin-jvm = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlin-kapt = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt", version.ref = "kotlin" }
```

Documentation is [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:conventional-dependencies-toml).

Answer (score 0):

Given your Gradle is in Kotlin format:

```kotlin
val javalinVersion = 5.3.2

dependencies {
  kapt("io.javalin.community.openapi:openapi-annotation-processor:$javalinVersion")
  api("io.javalin.community.openapi:javalin-openapi-plugin:$javalinVersion")
  api("io.javalin.community.openapi:javalin-swagger-plugin:$javalinVersion")
  api("io.javalin.community.openapi:javalin-redoc-plugin:$javalinVersion")

}
```

Then dependabot will create a single PR updating version variable.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this.

Comment: @ivan.ukr did you manage to check this out? Does it work for you?

Comment: We found some other solution.

Comment: @ivan.ukr can you share it - I'm curious how it can be achieved in the other way.

Comment: I've posted it in a separate answer.